# AngularJS Can we cache all scope data of an controller into service?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to cache page state in AngularJS app when user leaves the page to another page. I write a service to store all data.And when he comes back to the page, I load the data from service.

My Service:

```
var myApp= angular.module("myApp", ["ngResource"])
                    .factory("MaintainPageStateService",function(){
                             var service = {};
                             service.IndexPageData = {};
    
                             return service;
                    })
```

Html('/children.html' is controller by `childrenController` for example):

```
<div id="svgDiv" class="col-md-12" ng-controller="parentController">
                    <div ng-include="'/children.html'" style="height:100%">
                    </div>

</div>
```

In my parentController, I inject the serivce and save data before redirecting:

```
$scope.cacheAllData = function(){         
        MaintainPageStateService.IndexPageData = {               
             currentAreaReletion: $scope.currentAreaReletion,
             currentAreaInfoObjectId : $scope.currentAreaInfoObjectId,
             currentAreaInfo : $scope.currentAreaInfo,
             //....other properties
        }
     }
```

When user returns back, it will get the data from service:

```
$scope.readDataFromCacheService = function(){
         var indexData = MaintainPageStateService.IndexPageData;
         $scope.currentAreaReletion = indexData.currentAreaReletion;
         $scope.currentAreaInfoObjectId = indexData.currentAreaInfoObjectId;
         $scope.currentAreaInfo = indexData.currentAreaInfo;
       
         $rootScope.$broadcast('Initial_Data_From_Cache_Service');
     }
```

In childrenController:

```
$scope.$on('Initial_Data_From_Cache_Service', function (e) {
       var currentAreaReletion  =  $scope.currentAreaReletion;
      //here could not get data at all when I use second way of passing all scope
       
    })
```

Everything works well.
But is there any way to just `cache/save all scope data` instead of one by one manually since there may exist lots of properties?

When I try to use

```
$scope.cacheAllData = function(){
        MaintainPageStateService.IndexPageData = {
            scopeData : $scope
        }
     }
$scope.readDataFromCacheService = function(){
         var indexData = MaintainPageStateService.IndexPageData;
         $scope = indexData.scopeData;
         $rootScope.$broadcast('Initial_Data_From_Cache_Service');
     }
```

I get all data in `$scope.readDataFromCacheService` but its children controller could not get `$scope.currentAreaReletion` correctly, and it is `null`.

What is the problem?

Is this a right practice to save all scope data and read from service?

Answer (score 1):

I think persist the whole $scope may not be appropriate. $scope is glue between a controller and view. it has more things more than business data.e.g, Properties and parent/child relation maintained by Angular:

```
$$ChildScope: null
$$childHead: null
$$childTail: null
$$listenerCount: {}
$$listeners: {}
$$nextSibling: null
$$prevSibling: null
$$suspended: false
$$watchers: null
$$watchersCount: 0
$id: 6
```

$scope will always be new when you enter a view, there are lots of properties maintained by Angular, persist the whole $scope will make Angular hard to understand.

For example:
when you enter the page scope, the new scope will have always a different $id, even you enter the same view multiple times, it will give you different $id, it means it will always generate the new $scope object.

If you want to persist the whole page data, maybe you can try to put the data under the same data structure:

```
$scope.page1Data: {
    userData: {},
    orderData: {},
    ...
}
```

And persist page1Data in the service.

Comment: I understand your explanation and what I am doing now is just like your suggestion to put data into services manually, does it?

Comment: Have you debug line '$scope = indexData.scopeData;', i guess the scope has been destroied.

Comment: I debug in vs code by adding a breakpoint and it has correct data.Now, I decide to manually put the necessary business data into service.I want to ensure if this is a correct way to cache page state using memory(not localstorage)

Comment: I think putting data in service should be the correct way...

Comment: :) Maybe someone will give you better answer later